# Do USB microphone/headsets require special hardware?

Tags: usb, microphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a USB Headset require any Specific Soundcard?](https://superuser.com/questions/175684/does-a-usb-headset-require-any-specific-soundcard)

I have a new Thinkpad T-510. I'm thinking of getting a USB microphone/headset to use with my Dragon Naturally speaking software program. Do USB microphone/headsets typically work with most new laptops or do they require some special hardware?

Comment: The only special hardware needed is a USB port! :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a USB Headset require any Specific Soundcard?](http://superuser.com/questions/175684/does-a-usb-headset-require-any-specific-soundcard) Answer is given here! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Microsoft usb wireless headset. i was able to just plug it in and everything was installed. I'm sure it will work.
I have a Thinkpad T Sixty.

Answer (score 0):

I have the usb headset for using dragon at home. Personally, it didn't make an ounce of difference to the speed and quality of the input. This may be just my personal experience, but unless you can't type for some reason, the time and energy needed to 'train' it to your voice is better spent learning to type faster. I have yet to see it type faster than 25 words a minute, despite what the marketing says.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need any hardware. In theory USB is plug and play. This is true if the OS recognizes the device and has a driver for it. If not, you will need to load software on the computer, usually just a driver. For a mic and headphones, any recent version of Windows should already have the drivers.